Why was diamond removed from some MO moderators?
Tim Campion and Todd Trimble are currently not listed among the moderators. And their profile pages do not list them as moderators either.
At the same time, I haven't noticed some post on meta related to changes in the moderator team and the answer listing the moderators still shows the same users: History of MathOverflow.
Since the MO users might be wondering about this, I considered that asking on meta might be a reasonable thing to do. Is this just a temporary change? Or will they no longer be moderators?
It goes without saying that if this is related to some reasons which should not be revealed publicly, I am perfectly fine with an answer just stating this (or even with removing this question completely).
Since I saw related posts on some other sites, my first guess would be that it is just a technicality - not signing the updated moderator agreement within the given time limit.
Or perhaps not logging into the moderator interface for some time - there was one instance of this on MO in the past.  (See also: What is the process regarding moderator inactivity removals?)

Todd chose to quietly end his tenure after a long time of service, and Tim's expired for technical reasons and he hasn't chosen to renew it. The board is aware and has discussed the fact we are now two moderators fewer. More news later.

@DavidRoberts Thanks for the response! Perhaps this could even be an answer - naturally, I understand if you prefer to let them answer by themselves. (And I would like to thank them for their work in the moderators - no doubt many other users around here agree with with that.)

I'm confirming with others before I/we respond more.

For the sake of clarity, my comment above was not intended to be an answer, but a stopgap in order to forestall speculation in a vacuum.

@DavidRoberts Do the current moderators feel that the current number of moderators is enough? Or would there be a reason to elect some new mods to replace those we lost?

@SamHopkins watch this space. Discussions are happening.

Re: @DavidRoberts's last comment: see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/6067 now.

The decision to step down from being a moderator, effected in early September, was one I had planned to do quietly, without fanfare. There was no specific dramatic circumstance underlying it, and it was nothing like not signing the new moderator agreement.
I started in September 2013, so I'd been in this role about 11 years, which I figure is plenty long. As many of you know, for some years I had been the most visible and publicly active moderator. After Asaf Karagila, Tim Campion, Stefan Kohl, and David Roberts were elected, there was a major influx of new energy; after observing their capable stewardship for a while, I reckoned it was okay to step away.
Being a moderator was in many ways enjoyable, pretty much up until the recent flood of AI-generated nonsense. I've never considered myself technically savvy, which more and more looked like a requirement in order to deal with the changing scene, and it was making me nervous. In short, it wasn't much fun anymore, and I'm at a point in my life where I want fewer complications.
It was a pleasure to have done this though, and it was an important part of my life. I'm grateful for that opportunity, and how it brought me in contact with a lot of great people in this community.

Thank you for your service, Todd! The excellent leadership of MO over the past decade has made it a wonderful community to be a part of. But I do feel like you may be "burying the lede" here: if the recent surge of AI content has made life difficult for moderators, that might be worth a further discussion among all of the MO community.

Thank you, Sam. I'll just say that it's more difficult for nontechnical people like me. As you probably noticed, there are several discussions about AI currently on MO meta, but yes, still further discussion is needed.

May I add my "big thanks". I wish you all the best in your future projects, Todd. We will miss your community building efforts here at MO. I started out on MO 13 years ago, and I have very much appreciated your thoughtful moderator comments during all those years. Thank you.

Hi Todd - am a bit too busy for MO at the moment but just dropping by to also offer my appreciation of all your work and moderation, in both senses of the word. "They also serve who only stand and wait."

Another big thanks, Todd!  Mathoverflow has remained for a long time now an island of collegiality and meaningfulness (with just occasional lapses) in an increasingly degraded internet, and I appreciate how much hard work you and the other moderators have put into maintaining this.  Best of luck for all your other priorities now!

Carlo, Yemon, Peter -- thank you! Your words mean a lot to me, as I regard each of you with great respect. (Peter, sorry for the brevity of my greeting at CT 2024; I hope we can speak at greater length at a future meeting!)

If I understood correctly, the root cause for stepping down was the influx of AI content and its consequences, which is a bit saddening. Nowadays, this kind of degradation is evident almost everywhere and I really miss the good old internet. Thank you and best wishes.

Thank you Todd, for your excellent work in moderation (yes, in both senses of the word).

@FrancescoPolizzi May I return the thanks, for all your contributions in helping to maintain these sites (here and at main). It's been a pleasure.

It may not be surprising, but worth recording here that @ToddTrimble has been a particular pillar of MO behind the scenes as well!

Thanks, Ravi. Probably many people at MO are unaware of the enormous role you play. (While I'm here, I had wanted to find a way to thank @BillJohnson for an earlier comment, but I was too late. My apologies, Bill, if you see this.)

Just to fill folks in on my end: For awhile (for personal reasons) I had been finding myself not really able to keep up with my moderation and MO board responsibilities (minimal as they were). Over the summer I was asked to sign an updated moderator agreement, and somehow even that was too much for me. I took this as a sign that it was time to step down as a moderator, but I didn't acutally communicate this to anyone at the time. Sorry to cause confusion and disruption.
I've resigned as a moderator and board member. It's been a pleasure working with everyone. I'm hoping to return to being an active regular community member here.
Best,
Tim

Thank you Tim, for this explanation, but more importantly for all your contributions to MO and in moderation. Please take care.

I strongly second @DavidRoberts's comment!

Thanks, David and Ravi!
