Upcoming election announcement (2025)
As some of you have noticed, Tim Campion and Todd Trimble have stepped down from their moderator roles lately.
Consequently, the MathOverflow Board and the Moderator Team have agreed that it would be good to have election for new moderators coming up soon.
In the last election cycle, in the autumn of 2022, the community voiced complaints that a month notice was not enough. So we have decided to schedule the election to six months from now, which would land us in late April/early May. We will announce the final dates closer to the occasion, but this is an announcement, so that those who are considering this as an opportunity to contribute to the site on a different level can take the time to do so.
This election will see two new moderators positions available.

@Alex meta is also used for announcements. See my meta posting history, for example... people didn't vote to close my six strike update posts that I recall.
