Nominating other community members for the 2025 moderator election
As covered last election, there is no formal mechanism to elect other community members as potential moderation candidates, so this post will serve as an informal version of such.
If there are any users (besides yourself!) you think have the right stuff to moderate MO in the coming times, voice your opinions here!

Although it's easy to find, might still be worth linking to the announcement of the upcoming election here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/6067. In particular, worth noting that we will be electing two new moderators.

One can use the data dump to see who has the highest number of so-called moderating badges and then create a list to make the choice easier (maybe?)

@polfosol here you go - surprised to see I'm at 7, that definitely does not mean I'm qualified.

@Glorfindel I modified your query to also include date of last access.

I suggest for self-nomination Emil Jeřábek.
He is a high-caliber mathematician with extensive knowledge in his area; more importantly for moderation, he has been even-handed in multiple situations where he disagreed with me and others wanted to delete my answers, resulting in other users agreeing with him and leaving the posts happily alone.
I consistently see Emil striking a 'firm but fair' tone without really seeming to try, while other users seem to be trying to virtue signal about how fair and reasonable they are. I think he would be an excellent addition to the moderation team.

"self"-nomination?

@AnuragSahay I suppose I should have said ‘nominate’ according to the usage in my title, although nomination can be considered the action which formally submits a candidate for election, in which case Emil would be nominating himself when the election opens up.
